# Should I check-in compose.yml file to git repo when using docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is it best-practice to check-in `docker-compose.yml` file to Git repo when using Docker?

Comment: It is a part of the code base, so it is better to have it in repo. I'm not sure about your thought process, is there a concern you have?

Comment: It depends on the purpose of your docker-compose file. For example, if you are working in a team, and the docker-compose is for spinning up containers so that all the members of your team would have the same env for local development, then yes of course it should be committed to the repo, rather than each member of your team creating their own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, yes, absolutely. A `docker-compose.yml` file clearly documents how that various components of the project work together. Just ensure that it doesn't contain any sensitive information (like database credentials).